# Node.js HTTPParser doesn't call some of the callbacks

Tags: node.js, http, parsing

I'm playing with HTTPParser in Node.js v0.8.15. Unfortunately, some of the callbacks never get called.

For example, the following code invokes only `onHeadersComplete`. Couldn't manage to make it call `onURL`, `onHeaderField` and `onHeaderValue`.

```
var
    HTTPParser = process.binding('http_parser').HTTPParser,
    parser = new HTTPParser(HTTPParser.REQUEST),
    request = new Buffer(
        'GET /test HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Host: www.example.com\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:17.0) Gecko/17.0 Firefox/17.0\r\n' +
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n' +
        'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\n' +
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n' +
        '\r\n'
    );

parser.onURL = function() {
    console.log('onURL');
}

parser.onHeaderField = function() {
    console.log('onHeaderField');
}

parser.onHeaderValue = function() {
    console.log('onHeaderValue');
}

parser.onHeadersComplete = function() {
    console.log('onHeadersComplete');
}

parser.execute(request, 0, request.length);
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

For those who come here from a search engine.
Recent versions of Node use slightly different organization. This code works:

```
var HTTPParser = process.binding('http_parser').HTTPParser;

var parser = new HTTPParser(HTTPParser.REQUEST);

const kOnHeaders = HTTPParser.kOnHeaders | 0;
const kOnHeadersComplete = HTTPParser.kOnHeadersComplete | 0;
const kOnBody = HTTPParser.kOnBody | 0;
const kOnMessageComplete = HTTPParser.kOnMessageComplete | 0;
const kOnExecute = HTTPParser.kOnExecute | 0;

parser[kOnHeaders] = 
    function(headers, url) {
        console.log('kOnHeaders');
    }
parser[kOnHeadersComplete] = 
    function(versionMajor, versionMinor, headers, method,
             url, statusCode, statusMessage, upgrade, shouldKeepAlive) {
        console.log('kOnHeadersComplete');
    }
parser[kOnBody] = 
    function(b, start, len) {
        console.log('kOnBody');
    }
parser[kOnMessageComplete] = 
    function() {
        console.log('kOnMessageComplete');
    }
parser[kOnExecute] = 
    function() {
        console.log('kOnExecute');
    }

var ret = parser.execute(new Buffer(
        'GET /test HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Host: www.example.com\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:17.0) Gecko/17.0 Firefox/17.0\r\n' +
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n' +
        'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\n' +
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n' +
        '\r\n'
    ));
```

Alternatively, there are some wrapper modules.
The object currently has following methods:

- close - cancel parsing and free the parser (?)
- execute - read chunk of data and parse it. Could be called any number of times if the header is arriving slowly
- finish - tell parser there will be no data anymore, finish parsing
- reinitialize - prepare parser for another type of message (request/response)
- pause - IDK, maybe stop parsing on data addition
- resume - IDK, maybe start parsing
- consume - IDK, something for Stream
- unconsume - IDK, something for Stream
- getCurrentBuffer - return current data collector (?)

As for the usage details, you can refer to Node sources:

- https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_common.js
- https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_client.js

Answer (score 2):

`process.binding` is only supposed to be used by core node libraries.  From my brief reading of the source, the http parser C++ code only exposes a small subset of events (`onHeaders`, `onHeadersComplete`, `onBody`, `onMessageComplete`) so I believe these are the only events you can latch.

The parser uses some additional callbacks from the parser internally but they are not exposed up to JS land as events.

Answer (score 0):

On September 2021 doesn't work anymore:

```
$ node test.js
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)

$ node --version
v14.15.0
$ uname -a
Linux linux 5.4.0-84-generic #94~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 26 23:17:46 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Better use new http parser module https://github.com/creationix/http-parser-js

Then

```
npm install http-parser-js
```

and after that following code works:

```
HTTPParser = require('http-parser-js').HTTPParser;

var parser = new HTTPParser(HTTPParser.REQUEST);

const kOnHeaders = HTTPParser.kOnHeaders | 0;
const kOnHeadersComplete = HTTPParser.kOnHeadersComplete | 0;
const kOnBody = HTTPParser.kOnBody | 0;
const kOnMessageComplete = HTTPParser.kOnMessageComplete | 0;
const kOnExecute = HTTPParser.kOnExecute | 0;

parser[kOnHeaders] = 
    function(headers, url) {
        console.log('kOnHeaders');
    }
parser[kOnHeadersComplete] = 
    function(versionMajor, versionMinor, headers, method,
             url, statusCode, statusMessage, upgrade, shouldKeepAlive) {
        console.log('kOnHeadersComplete');
    }
parser[kOnBody] = 
    function(b, start, len) {
        console.log('kOnBody');
    }
parser[kOnMessageComplete] = 
    function() {
        console.log('kOnMessageComplete');
    }
parser[kOnExecute] = 
    function() {
        console.log('kOnExecute');
    }

var ret = parser.execute(new Buffer.from(
        'GET /test HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Host: www.example.com\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:17.0) Gecko/17.0 Firefox/17.0\r\n' +
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n' +
        'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\n' +
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n' +
        '\r\n'
    ));
```